# Flutter show gradient Divider top of ListView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

in this sample code which that have `ListView` and `Container` i would like to make simple gradient top of `ListView` when user is scrolling ListView items to right or left,

scrolling items to right should show gradient divider and scrolling to left should hide the divider, all of this visiblity should be have fade effect, could you help me how can i show and hide this gradient divider?

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() => runApp(SampleShadow());

class SampleShadow extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'sample',
      home: ShadowContainer(),
    );
  }
}

class ShadowContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _ShadowContainer();
}

class _ShadowContainer extends State<ShadowContainer> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final ValueNotifier<bool> showShadow = ValueNotifier<bool>(false);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.indigo.withOpacity(0.7),
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 100.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                ),
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      width: 50.0,
                      height: 50.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.indigo[400],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                        NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
                          onNotification: (scrollState) {
                            if (scrollState is ScrollEndNotification && scrollState.metrics.pixels >= 100) {
                              showShadow.value = true;
                              print('show');
                            } else {
                              showShadow.value = false;
                              print('hide');
                            }
                            return false;
                          },
                          child: ListView.separated(
                              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return Container(
                                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                  width: 50.0,
                                  height: 50.0,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.purple[400],
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100.0),
                                  ),
                                );
                              },
                              separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                                return const Divider();
                              },
                              itemCount: 50),
                        ),
                        ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
                            valueListenable: showShadow,
                            builder: (context, value, child) => value? Container(
                                  width: 10.0,
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                ): Container()),
                      ]),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this solution work fine, thanks to [@CopsOnRoad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6618622/copsonroad)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

void main() => runApp(SampleShadow());

class SampleShadow extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'sample',
      home: ShadowContainer(),
    );
  }
}

class ShadowContainer extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _ShadowContainer();
}

class _ShadowContainer extends State<ShadowContainer> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final ValueNotifier<bool> showShadow = ValueNotifier<bool>(false);
  AnimationController _animationController;
  Animation<double> _fadeInFadeOut;
  ScrollController _scrollController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
    _animationController = AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: kThemeAnimationDuration);
    _fadeInFadeOut = Tween<double>(begin: 0.0, end: 1.0).animate(_animationController);
    _animationController.forward();
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.offset >= 10) {
        showShadow.value = true;
      } else {
        showShadow.value = false;
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Directionality(
      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.indigo.withOpacity(0.7),
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Container(
          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: 100.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                ),
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      width: 50.0,
                      height: 50.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.indigo[400],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
                        ListView.separated(
                            controller: _scrollController,
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                width: 50.0,
                                height: 50.0,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.purple[400],
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100.0),
                                ),
                              );
                            },
                            separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return const Divider();
                            },
                            itemCount: 50),
                        ValueListenableBuilder<bool>(
                            valueListenable: showShadow,
                            builder: (context, value, child) {
                              if (value) {
                                _animationController.forward();
                              } else {
                                _animationController.reverse();
                              }
                              return FadeTransition(
                                opacity: _fadeInFadeOut,
                                child: Container(
                                  width: 10.0,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                                          begin: Alignment.centerRight,
                                          end: Alignment.centerLeft,
                                          colors: [Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5), Colors.transparent])),
                                ),
                              );
                            }),
                      ]),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```